# Java - Recursive Method that takes Cumulative sum in one array and returns another

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

So here is the problem: create a int [] recursive method that computes cumulative sums in the array numbers, and transform each value in the array by adding to the value the sum of values that precede it in the array. For example, if

numbers = [5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 1],
then

result = [5, (5)+6, (5+6)+7, (5+6+7)+2, (5+6+7+2)+3, (5+6+7+2+3)+1],

i.e.,result = [5, 11, 18, 20, 23, 24].

The caveats are: Cannot use static or void methods, cannot use loops.
Here is my code so far:

```
    public int[] computeCumulativeSums(int[] numbers){

    if(numbers.length == 0)
    {
        return numbers; // Base case
    }
    else
    {
        //recursive stage not implemented. Don't know how to implement
        return numbers; 
    }

}
//Helper method
public int [] addNumbers(int [] list, int index)
{
    if(index == 0)
    {
        return list; //Helper method base case
    }
    else
    {
                    //recursive case
        return addNumbers(list, index - 1);
    }
}

public boolean searchTable(int[][] data, int element){
    return true;
}


public static void main(String [] args){

    Recursion r = new Recursion();
        int[] numbers = new int[] {5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r.computeCumulativeSums(numbers)));  
}
```

Output: [5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 1]

What I'm asking is a push in the right direction because I'm so lost with this. Your help will be much appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State your strategy .. then code the recursive function. You would probably have something like:

```
function summit(array, i) ... 
    if i > 0, then set array[i]=array[i-1]+array[i]
    if i < array.length the call summit(array,i+1)
    return
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I like how you didn't spell it out for me... defeats the purpose of learning coding.

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend is: try to do it with a while loop.  The conditions. In the while loop is your stop condition. Now try to convert what is in the while loop into a recursive method (or if you can't, just a method, and then see how the each method could do the following call of the method itself). Does it help you?

Comment: Cannot use any loops. Recursion only.

Comment: I was talking about the process to find out what the recurrence was, a recurrence. a while loop can systematically be transformed to a recurrence. I just wanted to give an hint but it seems the solution was posted now ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args [])
{
   int [] array = {5,6,7,2,3,1};
   array = sum(array,0);
   for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
       System.out.print(" "+array[i]);
   }

}

public static int[] sum(int[] array, int index){
    if(index==array.length){
        return array;
    }
    if(index!=0){
        array[index] += array[index-1];
    }

    return sum(array,index+1);

}
```

Output: 5 11 18 20 23 24

Comment: Method cannot be static. Your method will work it's just that you remove static and then create an instance of the class in the main method. Thank you.